# Error con el lector de huella dactilar BioMini Plus 2

Tags: java, c#, biometrico

Hace poco realice un lector de huella digital para la empresa donde actualmente trabajo. Utilize el **Bio Mini Plus**, el código de ejemplo funcionaba correctamente, y todo bien, como nos expandimos como empresa, compraron nuevos equipos pero estos son **Bio Mini Plus 2** y bota la imagen a como a rayas.
Miren la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dieron el nuevo SDK y la misma cosa, veo en foros de Internet y todos le echan flores al lector, pero ninguno funciona.

Probé con la versión en Java y funciona a la perfección con los 2 modelos, y es lo que mas me desconcierta.

Probé la versión en android y falla con el biomini plus 2, pero con el 1 funciona perfectamente. No se si alguien le ha pasado lo mismo. Nose si desean algo de código pero creo que va mas halla de eso.

La solución es preferible en c#

Este es el método que captura la huella en Java:

```java
public void CapturarHuella(){
        int nRes =0;
        try{
            int [] EstaActivo = new int[1];
            BioMiniMain.UFS_IsCapturing(objDispositivoSeleccionado.Scanner, EstaActivo);
            if(!EstaEnUso()){
                 nRes = BioMiniMain.UFS_CaptureSingleImage(objDispositivoSeleccionado.Scanner);
                ObtenerHuellaDelLector();
                ObtenerTemplateHuellaDigital();
                this.SuscriptorHuellas.notifyObservers();
            }else{
                System.out.println("CapturarHuella(): No esta marcando");
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        if(nRes !=0){
            new Exception(String.valueOf(nRes));
        }
    }
```

y este es el método en C#

```c#
private void btnStartCapturing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            UFScanner Scanner;
            UFS_STATUS ufs_res;
            if (!GetGetCurrentScanner(out Scanner)) {
                return;
            }

            Scanner.CaptureEvent += new UFS_CAPTURE_PROC(CaptureEvent);
            ufs_res = Scanner.StartCapturing();
            if (ufs_res == UFS_STATUS.OK) {
                tbxMessage.AppendText("UFScanner StartCapturing: OK\r\n");
            } else {
                UFScanner.GetErrorString(ufs_res, out m_strError);
                tbxMessage.AppendText("UFScanner StartCapturing: " + m_strError + "\r\n");
            }
        }
```

Cualquier ayuda estaré muy agradecido.

Comment: saludos .. efectivamente seria bueno que agregases codigo con el que tienes problema...!!

Comment: Y el problema lo deseas resolver tanto de ANDROID como de C# ??

Comment: Por el momento seria bueno empezar en C#, ya que esta en produccion ese, el android es para llegar a lugares alejados.

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo c# con el que tiens problemas

Comment: Hola gabriel tengo algunos problemas, estoy iniciando con el sdk de suprema biomini me muestra el error UnsatisfiedLinkError: UFS_Init()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminé por hacerlo con el método en java ya expuesto, no me quedó otra opción.